# How to animate two jquery objects together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, frameset

I want to animate two jquery OBJECTS at the same time (using the jquery `slideUp` method)

I have two divs that have already been 'cached' into a variable like so:

```
var div1 = $('body').find('#someId');
var div2 = $('body').find('#someOtherId');
```

I have cached these because they take a considerable amount of processing to find due to the page layout (using framesets and frames...don't ask).

Anyway,

If I do the slide animation like below, they are not in perfect sync (they are lined up so you can easily see it visually)

```
div1.slideUp(500);
div2.slideUp(500);
```

So I tried wrapping it like so,

```
$(div1, div2).slideUp(500);
```

but only div1 slides.

Is there anyway to get this to work while still maintaining the cached objects?

**Edit:** Giving the div's a class name does not trigger the animation. I think it may have something to do with the fact that I'm using framesets. The jquery code is in the top frame and so it will not look into other frames for the class. That is why I cached the objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want like this:

```
div1.add(div2).slideUp(500);
```

I made a quick jsfiddle you can check out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MhHDc/).

Answer (score 3):

The shortest thing to do is to use a shared class and then select all the items with that class:

```
$('.willAnimate').slideUp(500);
<div id="element1" class="willAnimate"></div>
...
<div id="other-element" class="willAnimate"></div>
```

Otherwise, you could use the `.add()` method http://api.jquery.com/add/

In this case your code will become something like this:

```
div1.add(div2).slideUp(500);
```

Comment: The shared class will not work for me (see edit) but the jquery `add` does! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

why you dont add a class to the to div and add do the selector like this

```
<div id="someId" class="example"> </div>
<div id="simeOtherId" class="example"> </div>
```

the selector that add the animation it's like this

```
$(".example").slideUp(500);
```

and that avoid to find some variables and make more selectors

Answer (score 1):

Give the two divs the same class, i.e. `slide` and then change your code to `$('.slide').slideUp(500)`.

Comment: Is it not possible to give them the same class at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.yourclass').slideUp(500);

<div id="someId" class="yourclass"></div>
<div id="simeOtherId" class="yourclass"></div>
```